# How to perform lead conversion activity based on the email click in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, email, lead-conversion, automationstudio

I want to send an email to my leads with a clickable button with unique url. I want to put a trigger base activity which converts lead into opportunity as soon as user clicks on that button.

I know how to use Convert lead activity in journey builder but how do I associate this activity to click trigger. I want to trigger this as soon as someone click on that button, hence can't use engagement split either as it'll have a wait time.

Please someone guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Within a journey there is no possibility to listen for external events immediately except for the entry event. Therefore, you could add the convert lead activity to a different journey that is triggered by the processing page, which is accessed on button click.

This can be done via the REST-API (passing data can be done using AMPscript or SSJS) and an API entry event. Just be sure to include all the necessary information to identify the record in the button's link, so it can be passed to the new journey. It would be best to use encrypted information, so nothing is visible in plain text.

**Example code for firing an entry event using AMPscript:**

```vb
%%[
    SET @EventKey = "INSERT_EVENT_API_KEY_HERE" 
    SET @auth = '{"clientId": "INSERT_CLIENTID_HERE", "clientSecret": "INSERT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"}'
    SET @url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken'

    SET @returnCode = HTTPPOST(@url, "application/json", @auth, @response)
    IF @returnCode == 200 THEN
        SET @regex = '^{"accessToken":"(.*)",.*$'
        SET @accessToken = REGEXMATCH(@response, @regex, 1)

        SET @requestBody = CONCAT('{
            "ContactKey":"' ,@uniqueKey ,'",
            "EventDefinitionKey":"' ,@EventKey ,'",
            "EstablishContactKey":true,
            "Data":{
                "dataField1":"', @field1,'",
                "dataField2":"', @field2,'"
            }
        }')

        SET @url = CONCAT("https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events")
        SET @returnCode = HTTPPOST( @url, "application/json", @requestBody, @response, "authorization", concat("Bearer ", @accessToken))
    ENDIF
]%%
```

**Further information:**

- [Admit Contacts Via API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_admit_contacts_via_api.htm&type=5)
- [Fire an entry event: POST /interaction/v1/events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm)
- [Convert Lead Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_convert_lead_activity.htm&type=5)